# Is there a way to use boost::assign operators without polluting namespace?

Tags: c++, boost, namespaces, operators

I try to avoid "using namespace" in my C++ to avoid polluting my namespace. However, I would like to make use of boost assignment operators to do things like this:

```
std::vector tmp;
tmp += "abc","def","asdf","foo","blah","dfkef";
```

Without adding "using namespace boost::assign;" this produces an error:

```
error: no match for 'operator+=' in 'tmp += "abc"'
```

Is there a way to make use of these operators in boost without using the namespace?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're wrong in your assumption it will pollute the namespace: the `using namespace` feature was exactly created for this kind of uses.

It will only "pollute" the scope where the `using namespace` is declared, and in this case, the benefits (using the operators) is by far greater than the drawbacks (this "pollution" is as negligible as the size of the scope).

For example, you could have:

```
void foo()
{
   // no symbol of boost::assign is polluting here

   std::vector tmp;

   {
      using namespace boost::assign ;
      // brings in this scope all the symbols of boost::assign
      tmp += "abc","def","asdf","foo","blah","dfkef";
   }

   // no symbol of boost::assign is polluting here
}
```

You should decide a balance between the syntactic sugar brought by the `using namespace` and the potential pollution it could bring over.

A good compromise could be to limit it to a function body, or, if you are as paranoid as I am, create a scope just for this `using` statement...

As an amusing side note, the worst solution would be to put the using in a public header with exported symbols.

Comment: I think if your function is large enough where you can introduces scopes for `using` statements, your function should either be split up or your criteria was too strict, and the using statement has no effect on the rest of the function so there's no point in introducing scope.

Comment: @GMan: I guess you're right. This is why I wrote "A good compromise could be to limit it to a function body" and why writing a scope is qualified as "paranoid" ... ^_^ ....

Comment: You're right. I took a peek at the header files for assign and it looks like the definitions are very minimal, I suppose partially to facilitate using the namespace in this way.